# Trying to get property of non-object - using laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel

I am working on a project for university and I am trying to select all where the level is equal to the authenticated users level. I am getting an error "Trying to get property of non-object". I've tried looking at other questions here but no luck so far. Thanks in advance.

if you need me to show more code I can add it in here.

controller

```
        <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    // use App\Http\Requests;

    use DB;

    class Downloadcontroller3 extends Controller
    {
        //

        public function downfunc() {


         $downloads=DB::table('lessons')->where('level', auth()->user()->level)->get();
                    return view('download.viewfile3', compact('downloads'));



        }

       }
```

viewfile

```
<table class="table table-striped">


                    <thead>

                        <th> Title </th>
                        <th> Upload Date & Time </th>
                        <th> Level </th>
                        <th> Action </th>


                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        @foreach($downloads as $down)


                        <tr>

                            <td> {{$down->name}} </td>
                            <td> {{$down->created_at}} </td>
                            <td> {{$down->level}} </td>
                            <td> 

                            <a href="/~B00657229/workspace/COM559/prototype/test/storage/app/public/upload/{{$down->name}}"download="{{$down->name}}"> 

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">

                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"> Download </i>

                            </button>

                            </a>

                            </td>

                        </tr>





                        @endforeach


                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

Comment: Laravel errors say what line the error happened on in the Stack trace. As it is, this is vague, and we can only guess at what is throwing that error.

Comment: @TimLewis Line 18

Comment: And what is **on** line 18...?

Comment: The line that starts $downloads=DB::table

Comment: Then you should be able to deduct that `auth()` or `user()` is `null`, as trying to access a property (via `->`) of `null` will throw that error. Are you logged in when trying to run this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure, you are logged in. 
The user object is returning null because there is no user session.
If you're using Models as well you can tidy it up a little;

```
public function downfunc() {

     $user = Auth::user();
     $downloads = Lesson::where('level', $user->level)->get();
     return view('download.viewfile3', compact('downloads'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I realised after much investigation I wasn't logged in lol. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

More data is needed.
It is possible that `auth()->user()` does not return a user object, maybe it returns a null value, or maybe the error occurs in the view `viewfile3`, to pass data to the view would be better this way:

```
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']);
```

Comment: I have added my view file into the question above for your ref. I had use this auth()->user() before when calling auth()->user()->id)->get(); and this worked fine.

Comment: I tried removing ->level and leaving just auth()->user() and your right it returned nothing in the table.

Comment: Are you currently logged in when you call auth()->user() ?
If you are not logged in, the helper will return NULL.

Comment: SOLVED, I wasn't logged in and thats why it wouldn't work for me.